# How to add html and js file to image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I add a file to an image so when the image is clicked it runs the file? I would like when I click on a picture of a battleship it runs that game I wrote. The image is on line 30. There's two files, an html and JavaScript file. I tried looking it up myself but being so new to this I really could use some advice. Thank you!

my page is josephhyatt.com if you can review it.

Comment: Have you tried using onClick=Function() inside the <img></img> ?

Comment: what is the url of the game?

Comment: `I tried looking it up myself but being so new to all of this I really could use some advice` - look harder

Comment: i wrote the game on notepad++ and wanted to add the file to the webpage, its called battleship.html and battleship.js @ Mert Metin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `<img src="" onclick=functionName()/>` as @MCVNOOB said. This calls a certain function whenever the image is clicked on. If you change `functionName()` to the function that begins your game, your game will be executed when the image is clicked on.